# Is it normal to have a distinction between "business" and "engineering"?

Tags: software-industry, management, work-environment

I've been in the software business for over a decade but haven't changed many employers so my view of the industry is somewhat narrow.  However, in the limited experience I have, I've frequently come across this dichotomy between "business" and "engineering".

The premise is that the business is run by business people who know next to nothing about engineering, so there is a constant negotiation process between the two parties to agree on what to do next, and it is expected that they operate with opposing motivations (i.e. engineers want lots of time to do things, the business wants to launch fast, and so on).

Is this normal or typical, or just a sign of a dysfunctional software company? My instincts point me to the latter, but the lack of exposure to a variety of companies and teams tells me I could be wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Engineers have made good designs which are then changed by accountants…

Comment: This give-and-take is universal. "Dysfunctional" happens sometimes. More typically a suboptimal but functioning compromise. Knowing "next to nothing" about engineering is usually far from true, but that condition is not required for things to go wrong. Honest, capable people can have very diverging interests, given their assigned roles.

Comment: You'll have to define what "dysfunctional" means. Is the business delivering its goals and are you getting paid? Or do you mean some sort of academic definition of "dysfunctional"?

Comment: Far from being dysfunctional, if done right it is actually essential for product quality.  The engineers should be primarily motivated by the technical requirements and safety (latter possibly less relevant in software than other industries), while business and management are motivated by profit. I've seen many occasions of business leadership trying to make "technical" calls based on cost or schedule, which the engineers shoot down.  If they were the same people, this quality control function would be harder

Answer (score 15):

As others have said, it is absolutely normal for different parts of the organization to have different specializations, namely business and engineering. It's also normal for there to be different priorities.

However each should also recognize the skill set of the others. Engineers should appreciate that sometimes they have to do things differently for business reasons, and business people should also recognize that sometimes something cannot be done for engineering reasons, or that ignoring engineering priorities will have bad consequences down the road. It's when each side treats the other as opponents, or one expects that the others "just do what we tell them" that the problems happen.

Senior engineers should have some appreciation of business matters. But the most usual role where business and engineering are both needed is the Product Manager or Product Owner.

Comment: I think that engineers often pretend they have a greater difference from business than they do. You could say this helps foster a sense of team spirit within the engineers and promotes technical excellence. Likewise business people pretend that they're the only ones who're interested in the company making a profit. It's often done in a slightly jokey way. You often get this kind of rivalry between different departments in a company, and it's fine if it's lighthearted and underpinned by genuine respect and a bit of knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

> Is this normal or typical, or just a sign of a dysfunctional software
> company?

It's fairly normal, and not at all a sign of dysfunction in and of itself.

In many companies where I have worked, it's not quite as absolute as you portray. Often, many folks on the business side have at least some background in engineering. And many folks on the engineering side have some business background.

In addition, there are often roles like Product Management and Project Management that basically span both the engineering and business sides of the company.

For many years, I was a QA Director within R&D. I had both a technical background and a business background. I had a technical undergraduate degree along with an MBA. I had experience managing in a business IT department as well as managing in a technical engineering department.

And when I was a Vice President of Engineering, my work involved quite a lot of time with business issues as well as technical issues. It was necessary to mesh the two together.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this normal or typical

It's not typical but it's common enough to have different sections with different focuses. Normally marketing versus engineering, but could be any.

It's not dysfunctional in the sense that it cannot work. It's a bit inefficient, but often the engineers don't have the full picture either.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that you could describe as "normal" in business I would more describe it is as common. There are many companies that have a hard cut between "business" and "engineering" there are some that have no such cut and loads with grey areas in between.

Neither is right or wrong and it doesn't equate to a dysfunctional company per-say. I would look more into things like non technical people making technical decisions or the opposite. These are more signs of dysfunction.

Also note: lots of companies are dysfunctional doesn't mean they don't make money and pay well.

Comment: The situation in the last sentence is very important and often overlooked.

Answer (score 2):

You are over thinking this.  No two people in your company will have exactly the same goals and motivations, likewise no two teams and no two departments.

But different is not the same thing as opposed. Engineers want lots of time to do things because they want them to work, sales wants features to attract and keep customers.  Sales wants the features to work as well, because features that don’t work drive away both future and present customers.  Engineers also want to add the features as quickly as possible so they can move on to something else.  There’s not a fundamental conflict, but there is definitely room for different priorities and different understanding of what will work out the best.

The negotiations you describe are simply how an organization tries to work out the pros and cons of any particular action.

Even a one person company would have the same issues, it would just be done with less talking.

Answer (score 1):

If I assume by saying "business" you mean sales, then, I can say, the bridge between these two *seemingly* opposite entities is a role / functionality called Product (Program) Management.

In short - to state this in an over-simplified way, Sales gets the customers and their requirements, Product management translates the requirements to engineering problems (or work items) and prioritize them, and Engineering works towards solving those problems and delivery. Usually, I have rarely seen Sales to be directly engaging with Engineering, because then as you mentioned, there will be conflicts (lots of them). It's the job of the product management (team) to act as mediatory and ensure engineering (team) gets the  job done, while keeping the sales (team) expectations bound by reality.

In your case, maybe you (or your organization) are missing a functional product management team.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually there is no Sales as I’m talking about SaaS, and yes there is a product management department but, more or less, it simply receives requests from the CEO.

Answer (score -2):

### Average to bad

Ideally, you would have companies run by people who know technology very well, but also have keen business instinct and understand needs of a market. Think [Steve Jobs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs) or [Henry Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Ford). Of course, such people are rare, and worth their weight in gold. Companies having them are also rare, and would be advised to keep them as long as they can.

Next case would be something that could be called an average company, where you have perpetual tug-of-war between "accountants" and "engineers". If they are reasonable,  they would achieve some kind of compromise, which is never ideal. Sometimes they would overspend on some features that engineers wanted but not the market. Sometimes they would ruin good design by demands of business people. However, usually such companies trudge along, never great but never terrible either.

Finally, you have two types of companies that could be considered bad. First is "enthusiast" company, having no relation to actual market and business case, dedicating all the effort to some "holly grail" product that end up flopping. This usually happens in startups, but sometimes even established companies fall into trap. One example that recently came into my attention is [Konix Multisystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konix_Multisystem), that effectively financially ruined mother company.

Second example would be "greedy" company, especially those looking for short term profit. As a rule they would have a decent product by engineering standards, but then would ruin it by trying to milk it, without supporting R&D and heeding the warnings of their engineers. Again, one example of such behavior by technologically inept management, would be the story how [Irving Gould](https://www.commodore.ca/commodore-history/the-crazy-story-of-how-irving-gould-ended-up-owning-and-killing-commodore/) and [Mehdi Ali](https://www.commodore.ca/commodore-history/mehdi-ali-the-end-of-commodore/) ruined Commodore. It is usually taken as a warning what happens if technological company is run by non-technological people.

Overall, for you as and employee it could be worth your while to know in what kind of company you are, and to plan your future accordingly. Be aware that ruin could come suddenly, so if you deduce that you are working in a "bad" company it would be prudent to plan your exit before it crashes.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds absolutely normal!  [Sourav Ghosh has outlined one approach](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/181860/) (using SCRUM). In my experience it is the job of the IT Architect to bridge the gap between the business requirements and the technical solution, sometimes with a Business Analyst to help.

You might find this [Architecture Skills Framework](https://pubs.opengroup.org/architecture/togaf8-doc/arch/chap30.html) page from The Open Group Architecture Framework helpful.

Comment: In my experience Architects are usually very deeply technical and not usually or necessarily cognizant with the business side.

Comment: Interesting, not my experience (or career) at all!  Architects need to be able to speak business to business people and techy to tech folk.

Comment: I suspect both yourself and your down-voters are conflating "Solution Architect" and "Software Architect". These can be significantly different roles.

Comment: I'm talking more about what might be called an Enterprise or Lead Architect - someone who sits between the business and the techies and understands both. Not sure about the downvotes, I've being doing that job for 20+ years and am happy with the rewards :-)